# Using cookies in Exoplayer streams

Tags: android, kotlin, cookies, exoplayer

I'm trying to stream content from a URL that returns a 404 if you're not logged in or a 302 redirect if you are. To log in, I need to pass a cookie in the headers for Exoplayer's requests, but I'm struggling to work out how.

Previous answers suggest using a default Cookie Manager instance with your cookies already set. Others suggest setting the header as a map in HttpDataFactory.setDefaultRequestProperty. Neither has worked for me.

Here's my work so far.

```
val cookieManager = CookieManager()
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER)

val cookie = HttpCookie("identity", state.token)

cookieManager.cookieStore.add(URI("<URL>"), cookie)

if (CookieHandler.getDefault() != cookieManager) {
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager)
}

val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
    .setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.DEFAULT, true)
    .setMediaSourceFactory(
        DefaultMediaSourceFactory(context)
    ).build()

val session = MediaSession.Builder(context, player).build()

session.player.addMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(state.currentTrack.file.values.first()))
session.player.prepare()
session.player.play()
```

Hardcoding the URL to the redirected URL streams just fine, so I know it's an issue of just passing the relevant cookie. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code to add Cookie:

```
// Create a data source factory.
val factory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setDefaultRequestProperties(mapOf("Cookie" to cookieValue))
// Create a progressive media source pointing to a stream uri.
val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory)
.createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(videoUrl));
// Create a player instance.
val player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
// Set the media source to be played.
player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
// Prepare the player.
player.prepare();
```

[Code is taken from here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer/progressive#using_progressivemediasource)

Another option is to use [OkHttpDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media3/datasource/okhttp/OkHttpDataSource.Factory?authuser=1) in case you are using OkHttp/Retrofit with cookies in your app.